# Gradle Buildship project dependency cycle false positive

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, buildship

So I've got a multi-project gradle build consisting of:

```
myapp
myapp2
shared
testLib
```

Where `myapp` and `myapp2` have compile dependencies on `shared`.

The `testLib` project also has a compile project dependency on `shared`.  It exists to define some unit test helper code which uses `shared` classes.  These classes live in its `main` sourceSet, as the purpose of this project is to build library containing test helper classes.

Now the `shared` project has unit tests.  These tests utilize the helper code in `testLib`.  Thus `shared` has a **testCompile** project dependency on `testLib`.

Gradle has no problem with this.  It understands to first build `shared`, then build `testLib`, then run the unit tests in `shared` just fine.  **Buildship** however, does not.  It flags this as project dependency cycles after I import the build: "A cycle was detected in the build path of project 'shared'. The cycle consists of projects {shared, testLib}." and a similar message for the `testLib` project.

So why not just roll `testLib` into the test sourceSet of `shared`, you might ask?  Well, the thing is, some of that unit test helper code is also used by the unit tests in `myapp` and `myapp2`.  Both of these projects have compile project dependencies on `shared` and testCompile project dependencies on `testLib`.

Is there any way to get Buildship to understand that this is not really a project dependency cycle?

**EDIT:**

I have tried part of the solution here: https://softnoise.wordpress.com/2014/09/07/gradle-sub-project-test-dependencies-in-multi-project-builds/ changing my testLib build to this (after moving the test helper class back into the `test` sourceSet from `main`):
    plugins {
      id 'java'
    }

```
configurations {
    testOutput
}

dependencies {
  compile project(':shared')
}

task jarTest (type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.test.output
    classifier = 'test'
}

artifacts {
    testOutput jarTest
}
```

and changing my `shared` project to reference the new `testLib-test.jar` via:

```
testCompile project(path: ':testLib', configuration: 'testOutput')
```

Still no luck.  Once again gradle has no issues and builds fine, but after deleting and re-importing the project in eclipse, Buildship returns the same cycle warnings as before.

Is Buildship just currently unable to handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is happening because, eclipse has only a single `classpath` for the whole project (for both main and test). So where as gradle `compile` and `testCompile` as two different configurations - when importing into eclipse you will find issues.

You need to get rid of one of the dependencies. May be you can create a separate project for tests from testLib.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I suppose I could completely separate all the test code into a parallel project hierarchy which lives alongside the now test-less main project code.  Then the eclipse classpaths for each set of projects would be cycle-less.  I was just hoping someone might know a better solution.